# Android webview div style="height: auto" displays black screen

Tags: android, html, webview, height

I am using webview to display html pages in an android application. I was having difficulty with scrolling so used scrollview and set the height of the div to auto style=”height:auto;”. That solved the scrolling issue perfectly.

However, this led to another issue that because the height of the div is set to auto, if the div is say 200px, then nothing appears after the  tag. This means that whenever the div is less than the height of the screen the remainder of the screen is black. Is there any way to set the background of the empty part of the screen to white instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am back and i finally found a solution - typically, it was simple but hopefully someone else can benefit from it.

basically all I had to do was in the main.xml file change the background from black to white as follows

android:background="#ffffff"

and that was that!